# Where do I put the Google API .json key file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-api

I am trying to integrate Google Calendar API into my Rails app, so I can create Google calendar events from my app.

Google has provided a client_secret.json file. I can use it locally, but now have no idea how to implement the key file on heroku.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

It should just be a secret and key (the names and values).

For heroku, you can set them as environment variables. Like so:

```
heroku config:set GOOGLE_SECRET=8N029N81ASLDKFA823_WO4ANF
```

(but please use the information provided in your json file)

Now.  The next step is to make sure that your application only calls for those keys in a single way.  An option is to use the config/secrets.yml file.  Call to the environment variable in the secrets file.  Then, you can use the dotenv gem in development so you have .env file in your application's root where you place all your env vars (but do NOT check in the .env file)

Create a file if it doesn't exist `config/secrets.yml` and inside it add:

```
 production:
   google_secret: ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET']

 development:
   google_secret: ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET']
```

(obviously, again, make sure the name is what you choose)

Next add dotenv to your gem file and run bundle

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
```

Create a new file called .env in the app's root.  And add your variable directly including both the key name and the value.

```
GOOGLE_SECRET=8N029N81ASLDKFA823_WO4ANF
```

You can add as many env variables as you need to.

Now edit the .gitignore file and add  the .env file to it, to make sure you don't accidentally check in your private information.

Lastly, in any place that you need to USE the environment variable, is to call it from secrets like so:

```
Rails.application.secrets.google_secret
```

I know it seems like a lot of steps, but it will ensure that you dev matches your prod without making a lot of `if Rails.env.development?` statements in your code.

Comment: I tried to do that actually. I set the secret and id from the json file, but that doesn't work. The Google client is looking for the file itself.

Comment: Google's API Client gem [Docs link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ruby)

Comment: Aaaaaah---  I see.  Square peg, round hole :)  The docs are for a pure ruby setup.  It's still using the same information in a rails setting, but instead of using the rb script provided in that documentation, you'll just use the OAUTH method instead.  You'll still be able to use the steps above, you just need to tell your script where and how to use the information in it.  Also, note that because you're using heroku and its an ephemeral filesystem, that script in google's tutorial tries to write to the FS, which isn't possible on heroku.

Comment: Right. I've been driving myself crazy trying to make this script work. I've already got the ENV variables set in heroku & secrets.yml. Well, I have the client_id, secret & calendar_id set. I'll just have to sit and think about how to write a new script to use them.

Comment: If its a user-calendar (coming from their google account) you can use omniauth to connect to their calendar, and once you have the secret you can follow this tutorial: http://landonmarder.com/posts/2014/06/04/google-cal-rails/ --- If you're not using use-based calendars that doesn't help tho

Comment: I'm using one specific calendar for all events from the app, so I won't have individual users signing in through omniauth. I'm sure there must be a way to accomplish that, I just haven't found it yet.